# Google App Engine Task Queue Error using Python API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue, flask

I've implemented a task queue action for a Flask + GAE project I'm playing with to learn more about Python web dev and I'm getting the following error, and I cannot track down any information about it.

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('0.1.0.2', 80)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in    _handle_request_noblock
self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 311, in process_request
self.shutdown_request(request)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 459, in    shutdown_request
request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
AttributeError: 'FakeConnection' object has no attribute 'shutdown'
----------------------------------------
```

I have a view that is accepting a POST request from another view in my application, and as far as I can tell it is doing all the processing that I am expecting except it gets to the end and spits this out.  I'm guessing this because I see this output in the GAE devserver log:

```
INFO     2011-01-23 21:41:16,865 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /main/new HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-01-23 21:41:23,753 dev_appserver.py:3317] "POST /main/new HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2011-01-23 21:41:24,528 dev_appserver.py:3317] "POST /tasks/check_for_spam HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The check_for_spam stuff is a function that runs some data through the Defensio API to determine if it is spam or not.  Here's the code

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

from application.models import LieModel
from defensio import *

class SpamChecker(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        id = self.request.get('id')
        client = Defensio('577709b41d42f2c34f80cd57d50333d6') 
        q = LieModel.all()
        q.filter("id = ", id)
        results = q.fetch(1)

        for result in results:
            title_doc = {'content': result.title, 'type': 'comment', 'platform':'python'}
            body_doc = {'content': result.body, 'type': 'comment', 'platform':'python'}
            title_status,title_response = client.post_document(title_doc)
            body_status,body_response = client.post_document(body_doc)
            lie_is_spam = False

            if title_status == 200 and title_response['defensio-result']['spaminess'] > 0.5:
                lie_is_spam = True

            if body_status == 200 and body_response['defensio-result']['spaminess'] > 0.5:
                lie_is_spam = True

            if lie_is_spam:
                lie_k = db.Key.from_path('Lie', id)
                lie = db.get(lie_k)
                lie.delete()


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('/tasks/check_for_spam', SpamChecker)
        ]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that it was using Python 2.7, so how do I tell dev_appserver.py I want so use (for exmample) python2.5 on my Macbook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem went away with Robert Kluin's suggestion.  I'm starting up the dev server by using

```
python2.5 /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py .
```